# Grouped barchart for multiple dummy variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am trying to create a bar chart that shows the mean damage corresponding to 0 and 1 values for multiple dummy variables, but I really have no clue where to start.

[image: Here the head of my data]

[image: Maybe this illustration helps to understand]

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Your question might be tailored to your specific dataset, so it is important that you share your data, at least you can share an small example dataset

Comment: @Quinten I've added a small overview of my data, ignore the NAs

Comment: Please do not provide data as image. We cannot work with it and if you ask people to copy it manually you most likely won't get any answers. You can get help for free so please do not make us do stupid typing jobs. Use `dput(df)`as suggested by @Quinten or maybe `dput(head(df))` if the data set is large.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = subset(stack(df), !is.na(values)), aes(x = ind, fill = as.factor(values))) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", na.rm = T) +
  labs(fill = "values")
```

Output:

[image]

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(d1 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0),
                 d2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,0),
                 d3 = c(1,0,1,0,0,1),
                 d4 = c(0,0,1,0,1,1),
                 d5 = c(NA, 0,1,0,1,NA),
                 d6 = c(0,1,1,0,1,NA),
                 d7 = c(1,1,1,NA,0,0),
                 d8 = c(1,1,1,0,1,0))
```